# Debugging test c# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I have the following method in a class...

```
public Boolean isMemberOf(string user, int league) {
        Boolean isPlayer = false;
        var leaguePlayer = db.GameworldPlayers.Count();
        if (leaguePlayer > 0) {
            isPlayer = true;
        }
        return isPlayer;
    }
```

Simply, this method will accept a player and a league and return whether or not this league has this player.

So I am writing test to test this behaviour... I realise that this test is a bit useless since I don't use user or league, but I have powered it down to at least get it to run with a simple count.

```
[TestFixture]
public class GameWorldTests
{
    [Test]
    public void logged_in_user_is_a_gameworld_player()
    {
        GameworldPlayerOperations gwp = new GameworldPlayerOperations();
        Assert.IsFalse(gwp.isMemberOf("ewijfeiw", 1));
    }
}
```

My test is failing... which isn't what I expected. So on debugging my test I found that the method was crashing my application with the following message:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

I have never seen a message like this before. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

Thanks.

Comment: `"See the inner exception for details."` - What are the details?

Comment: Invalid object name 'dbo.GameworldPlayers' - it is included in my context tho...    public DbSet<GameworldPlayer> GameworldPlayers { get; set; }.

Comment: Your unit test (actually it's an integration test) apparently doesn't connect to the right database.

Comment: so my test doesn't connect to the right db. ok i can see why that would be the case. can you tell me how i can specify such a thing for my test project? or perhaps for a different slant on things, am i setting up my tests all wrong?

Comment: ok - i was able to add a connection string to the app.config file for my test project. now i'm getting the results expected. many thanks for taking the time to look everyone.

Comment: Your method is really hard to test. The test result will depend on the data in the context, so you are having an integration test. Use an interface (call it ILeagueQueries) and use that in your method. Now you can test without the database and do a real unit test.